# SVN Update without Downloading all the files

Tags: svn

I googled a lot for this topic but i couldn't find anything on it. So i am asking it here.

I have setted up a SVN Repository on a remote server. I have already added my updated project source folder to the repository.

Now, since, i am trying to use SVN for my project, I need to update and commit from my local project source folder. Which creates a source folder copy on local machine by downloading everything from the svn repository. I am looking to avoid that download.

The source in the repository and in my local copy is same. Now i only want to add and commit things which i'll do further in the project.

My Question is that, Is it possible to update project folder without downloading the whole project source from the repository which we do first time when we checkout the project source from the repository. I have a low bandwidth connection and source code is big enough that if I checkout whole source folder. It will take a lot of time.

I have the source code copy with me which I want to work on and only commit new changes in the repository.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't understood why you've mentioned `git`. Likely you have a pure `svn` repository, w/o `git-svn` gate, right?

Comment: Sorry, I removed git. I just added it because it was coming up in the recommendation. Yes, I have a pure SVN repository.

Comment: In what way did you add your project's folder to the repository? From your comments on answers, it sounds like you did this without a working copy on your machine, somehow, maybe with `svn import`? Or did you actually use `svn add` and `svn commit` to get your project on the server?

Comment: I right click on project folder and click Import in the TortoiseSVN menu....selected the repository and clicked Ok....and it added that in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, only checkout what you need.  For example, if all the files you need are under `http://server/svn/trunk/foo`, do a checkout from `svn co http://server/svn/trunk/foo` and not at `http://server/svn`.

A lot of people who are use to Git (where you *clone* the entire repository) to Subversion get confused by this. When they're told that the repository is at `http://server/svn`, they will attempt to checkout `http://server/svn` which will give them every branch and tag in the repository, and will likely fill up their drive with hundreds of gigabytes of data. In Subversion, you just checkout the project itself on the branch or trunk you need.

You can also use the `--depth` option and `--set-depth` options for checkouts and updates to create what is called a *sparse checkout*. For example. Let's say your project contains source, documentation, javascript, QA tests, and architecture plans. Doing this:

```
~$ svn co http://server/svn/trunk/proj
```

will get you tons of files you don't want. You can use these options to trim down what you don't want:

```
~$ svn co --depth=none http://server/svn/trunk/proj
A proj
```

The only thing you have is the empty `proj` directory. Now, you can go in and do an update to the code you actually want:

```
~$ cd proj
proj$ svn update --set-depth=infinity source javascript
A source/...
A source/...
A javascript/...
A javascript/...
```

Now, only the `source` and `javascript` directories are downloaded. The rest of the project which includes the documentation, architecture documents, etc. are not downloaded.

And, it stays set this way. Doing this:

```
proj$ svn up
```

will not download any of the directories you don't want while downloading the updates to the `source` and `javascript` folders.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Basically, i was saying is that. I have a copy of source code on my local machine which i have add to the new repository i created on a remote server. Now, i don't want to checkout the same source from the repository and work on that source. Instead i want to work on my local copy and commit only new changes. I want to save my download time because that is of no use when i have the source code already which i added myself to the repository.

Comment: Subversion tracks the state of you working directory with information stored in the `.svn` directory. So, even if you have those files, you need to do a fresh checkout to get that `.svn` directory. However, it should take that long to do the initial checkout, and once done, you can use `svn updste` to maintain it. The largest project we have is about 1/4 gigabyte and contains over 10,000 files. It takes less than five minutes to checkout over my corporate VPN. There might be ways of tricking svn into using your files, but it's probably not worth the risk.

Comment: Yeah, Even i was thinking there must be a way to tweak the SVN. That's why I thinking if i can avoid the huge download. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have:

> - trunk
>
>   - foo
>   - foo2
>   - foo3

To update single folder from trunk, use:

```
svn update trunk/foo
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Basically, i was saying is that. I have a copy of source code on my local machine which i have add to the new repository i created on a remote server. Now, i don't want to checkout the same source from the repository and work on that source. Instead i want to work on my local copy and commit only new changes. I want to save my download time because that is of no use when i have the source code already which i added myself to the repository.